# implicit function theorem in multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

My question that in multivariable calculus the implicit function theorem states that:

if $F(x,y)$ and $y=f(x)$, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(F\right)}{\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(F\right)}$$

I have a $2$ problems with this

$1-$ $F(x,y)$ $and$ $y=f(x)$ so his means that the function $F$ is a function of one variable which is $x$

$2-$ while we were computing $partial$ $derivatives$ we treated $y$ and $x$ as two independent variables although that $y$ changes as $x$ changes but while doing the $partial$ $derivatives$ w.r.t $x$ we treated $y$ and $x$ as two independent varaibles and considered $y$ as a constant

Comment: In $F(x,y)$ it is a variable. In $y=f(x)$ it is the function value.

Comment: Usually it is formulated like this: if  $F(x_0,y_0) = 0$ and derivative of $F$ with respect to $x$ is "not zero" at $x_0$ then, in some neighborhood of $x_0$ there is a function $ y= y(x)$ so that $F(x,y(x)) = 0$. I think it is really helpful to draw a picture here in the dimension 2. That is, you have a surface ( graph of F) which touches x-plane at $(x_0,y_0)$ and if derivative of $F$ with respect to $x$ is not zero then the graph of $F$ really crosses $x$ plane along a curve. This curve is the graph of $y = y(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $F$ is by definition a function of two variables $x$ and $y$. It is trivial that we can take two partial derivatives of it.

This $F$ implicitly defines a function $f(x)$ of one variable by the constraint
$F(x,y)=c$ where $c$ is a constant.

The correct equation for $f'(x)$ you obtain from the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}F(x,f(x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,f(x))+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F(x,f(x))f'(x).
$$
Now observe that the LHS of this is zero because we said $F(x,f(x))$ is constant.
Can you solve this equation now for
$$
f'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}\quad ?
$$

Comment: But in order to take partial derivative the two variables must be independent
but in this case $F(x,y)$ $=$ $0$ and this defines an implicit function which is 
$y$=$f(x)$ so the two variables are not independent

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. I believe that the confusion comes from writing $dy/dx$ instead of $f'(x)$ . Better to treat $y$ as an independent variable of $F(x,y)$ . Avoid mixing it up with $f(x)$.

Comment: I've searched for a solution and I found this paper (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwik7_792fX3AhWBOuwKHYx4C3EQFnoECDQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.cmu.edu%2F~cnewstea%2Fteaching%2Fold%2Fteaching%2F21-256%2Fimplicit-partial-diff.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0B5pNq4LIWmEyF2W32jT5K)

Comment: I don't see anything new in there. If it helps why not.

Comment: it resolved my confusion because:
in this paper it's written that we treat $x$ and $y$ as being totally independent from each other so we can compute their partial derivative 
my confusion was if $y$=$f(x)$ why while doing partial derivative we treat it as a constant although it is a $function$ in $x$ and it changes while $x$ changes